# Openlayers 2 - zoom to multiple coordinates

Tags: openlayers-2

I have multiple asset icons on a map

I want to be able to zoom to show all icons on the map
I have the Lat and Long of each asset

Currently, i have it working with 1 asset as I can use this code to zoom to the asset
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(obj.d[k].vLongitude, obj.d[k].vLatitude).transform(WGS84, map.getProjectionObject()), map.getZoom());

Do I need to pass in an array of co-ordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create coordinate list

```
var obj={};
obj.d=[];
obj.d[0] ={};
obj.d[0].vLongitude = 45; 
obj.d[0].vLatitude= 45; 
obj.d[1] ={};
obj.d[1].vLongitude = 55; 
obj.d[1].vLatitude= 55;
```

create a markers layer

```
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
            map.addLayer(markers);
```

and add all markers on map

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.d.length;i++){ 
 var size = new OpenLayers.Size(25,25);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/api/img/zoom-world-mini.png',size,offset);
            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(obj.d[i].vLongitude,obj.d[i].vLatitude),icon));
}
```

and

zoom to data extent

```
map.zoomToExtent(markers.getDataExtent());
```

Comment: You could do this with a list and append. Creating a dict for a lat/lon pair is kind of overkill, though the overall approach of getDataExtent is good.

Comment: Thanks! I'm been struggling to get this working
Its putting an icon in the sea in Gulf of Guinea, not sure what thats all about!

Comment: using dev tools in chrome i can see the markers:array has 3 objects and maxExtent has the same values for top, right, bottom, left: -20037508.34

Comment: ok kinda got it working, but i'm not sure how to get rid of the marker... it seems i'm using vectors and not markers, dont suppose you have a VECTOR example?

Comment: hi, getDataExtent function is avaible to vector layer. more information is http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getDataExtent

and add feature in vector layer 

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.addFeatures


example :
var vector= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Vector" );
            map.addLayer(vector);
for(var i=0;i<obj.d.length;i++){ 
vector.addFeatures([
new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(obj.d[i].vLongitude,obj.d[i].vLatitude))])
}

Comment: vector.getDataExtent();